# Shadows are normal in cycles preview but turn into reflections when rendered out

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

Hi I have been following the blender 2.8 donut tutorial and I am currently at the stage where I need to render and texture it so I did a quick render to see how my donut looked but for some reason the plane reflects the donut? The shadows look fine in cycles but every time I render it out I get this weird reflection I went into the shade editor to see if maybe my plane had a reflective material but there was nothing at all. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what I see in the render I don't think they are reflections, I think you have a duplicate of the mesh that is hidden. Press Alt+H to show the hidden objects and see if those duplicate meshes appear. If the problem does not appear, maybe you can share the project to review it.

Comment: Thank you so much you're a life saver I had to use the filter to disable the hidden object in renders